# It's a duty + infinitive Vs. It's a duty + gerund

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, syntax

In the sentence:

> It's a duty **to take** the bus to Barcelona, the most beautiful city in Spain.

Shall I use the infinitive or the gerund after "duty"?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you have to do is clarify what you want the sentence to say. I think there's a translation problem here. The sentence says that "It's a **duty** to take the bus to Barcelona". One way of understanding this is that "If you go to Spain, then you **absolutely {must/have to}** go to Barcelona because it's the most beautiful city in the country!"

A **duty** is an **obligation**; that is, it's something that you **{must/have to} do**.

Therefore, the sentence should probably be something like this:

> "If you go to Spain, then you **must** go to Barcelona by bus, because it's the most beautiful city in the country, and the bus ride is allows you to see the gorgeous countryside."

You can use a gerund too:

> "If you go to Spain, **taking** the bus to Barcelona is **a must**, because it's the most beautiful city in the country, and the bus ride is allows you to see the gorgeous countryside."